# HTML to Dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to read an local HTML file with pandas so I can convert it to a Dataframe but I am getting this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5'

```
df = pd.read_html(loca_url)
```

I am sending the file attached so you can download it and try.
Thanks for your help in advanced.

[Html file](https://grupomdmoldes-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ruidinis_mdgroup-global_com/EQLllxoO3PlGtBfbSHomFLABhNoruY3IgbOp4toBhOqjoA?e=HcAwuy)

Comment: What is the type of `loca_url`?

Comment: I have attached the file. It is an HTML file created by a software we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with html file in line 32:

```
<th colspan="0.5" >Material: </th>
```

According to [html documentation](https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/) colspan attribute should be an integer.

You need to fix the above mentioned line to:

```
<th colspan="1" >Material: </th>
```

or another desired integer. Changing it to 1 solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you MarcinKamil, my problem is that I have more than 500 files like this. Is there a way you would suggest to change them all ? Maybe the files with beautiful soup and change that value in memory only and then convert it to a Dataframe ? But not sure how.

Comment: I tried using Beautiful Soup on your example file with no success, but I admit I'm not that fluent with it. From my perspective creating the files again would be first step. If not possible and if the `<th colspan="0.5" >Material: </th>` repeats in all of them I'd use Notepad++ replace function; you can apply it to the whole folder as batch there.